# Rails: I want to stub Time.now but it won't be stubbed in scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, scope, stub

I have such scope

```
  scope :old,   joins(:group).where("`users`.`created_at` <=
        DATE_SUB(?, INTERVAL `groups`.`check_minutes` MINUTE)", Time.now)
```

I stub `Time.now` as following

```
  Time.stub!(:now).and_return(Time.parse("1 JUL 2010"))
```

I want scope `old` to use this stubbed `Time.now` but it uses current time.

I suppose rails create scopes when load model first time (e.g. when load `spec_helper.rb`), so we stub Time.now after loading the scope. Is it true?

So I found two solutions:

1. Reload User model after stubbing Time.now and before using scope
2. Use regular method instead of stub like this

Do you have more elegant solutions?

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/276-testing-time-web-requests

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having `Time.now` in a plain scope is undesirable, as you state the scope is setup when the model class is loaded, so a long running Rails process may have a scope that is from hours or days ago. The stubbing issue is a side-effect of this undesirable situation.

I would suggest you rewrite your scope using a `lambda`, so that `Time.now` is always queried. This will alleviate the stubbing issue and always get the latest `Time.now`.

```
scope :old,   lambda { joins(:group).where("`users`.`created_at` <=
        DATE_SUB(?, INTERVAL `groups`.`check_minutes` MINUTE)", Time.now) }
```

I'm not a huge fan of the lambda syntax here, but it does do the job.

Comment: Thanks! I decided to use `def old ... end`.